# Android build fails in codenameone build sever

Tags: codenameone

My android build fails after build and this is the error log i get
Total time: 1 mins 16.631 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':dexRelease'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=5907, address=[10331ba5-2501-41cc-aa13-52a0ba46bd51 port:41817, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2862cb6d-50e8-4321-a1fa-590435e89f0f,javaHome=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=5907,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1500m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/video-new-defaults-barcode-qrcode-changes.html

You can workaround this by using `android.gradle=false` in the build hints. However, I'm guessing its related to some cn1lib or build hint you added. But it seems the build error log you provided is partial so I don't see any issue there.